# single row query returns more than one row (but there is no internal query)

Tags: sql, oracle

When i am running this query i am getting the error -
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
*Cause:
*Action:

```
SELECT
JOB_ID
,SRC_EXTRACT_DT_TM as EXTRACTDATE
,TECH_PEIN
,REASON_FOR_CALL
,CALL_BACK_NO
,JOB_COMPLT_DT_TM as JOB_COMPLT_DATE
,CUST_NAME as CUSTOMER_NAME
,STREET_NO as STREETNUMBER
,STREET_NAME
,CITY
,PROVINCE_CODE as PROVINCE
,POSTAL_CODE
,SERVICE_ADDRESS
,WORK_TYPE_CODE as WORKTYPE_CD
,TO_CHAR(SRC_UPDATE_DT_TM, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as LASTUPDATED
,RELATED_ORDER_ID AS RELATEDORDERID
,RELATED_ORDER_UPDATE_DT_TM AS LASTORDERRELATEDUPDATE
,JOB_TYPE as JOBTYPE
,JOB_CREATION_DT_TM as CREATIONDATE
,JOB_DUE_DATE as DUEDATE
,JOB_CATEGORY
FROM W6ADMIN.VIEW_EDW_PCCS_HOURLY
WHERE SRC_UPDATE_DT_TM > TO_DATE('2018-05-03 09:02:41','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' )
AND SRC_UPDATE_DT_TM <= TO_DATE('2018-05-03 09:02:41','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' )+('24'/24)
```

As i am aware of this error, it only comes when there is a internal query that is returning more than one value for external query but here it is strangely throwing this.

On my further investigation i found that only for particular 2 field in this select query it is failing(TECH_PEIN, JOB_COMPLT_DT_TM as JOB_COMPLT_DATE). On excluding this two fields from query and then executing i am able to get the data, only this fields data i am not able to see. Please provide the reason and solution for this error.

Comment: `W6ADMIN.VIEW_EDW_PCCS_HOURLY` - given its name, probably a view. Given the error, probably a buggy view.

Comment: Have you checked view W6ADMIN.VIEW_EDW_PCCS_HOURLY?  I bet the issue is inside there

Comment: Please provide sample data, table structures and the expected output

Comment: The view `VIEW_EDW_PCCS_HOURLY` is bad. Please post the `create view` statement.

Comment: As others have pointed out, the error does not come from your query directly, but from the fact, that you are referencing a view, which has such an issue in its query.

Comment: yes that's a view... I don't have access to original table. i have checked with view definition, there are no key, no null or not null constraint has been assign to any field. TECH_PEIN and JOB_COMPLT_DT_TM (i.e. issue fields) both fields are VARCHAR.

Comment: To be clear my question for particular record it fails... And for that particular row... I am unable to see the value for mentioned two frields i.e. TECH_PEIN AND JOB_COMPLT_DT_TM and rest of all rows data is extracted from this table including these fields too. Is it possible that there must be data of these fields because of i am getting error